# How to load an index page without a controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a question and apologies if it is too simple but I really couldn't figure it out. If I have my domain for example: www.shop.com. I changed .htaccess to omit the need for index.php. Now I am wondering how can I load for example a page (main home page) without having any controller in url address. E.g.:

www.shop.com =========> should land me on the home page of my site.

currently the only way I can do it is by defining a controller and doing this:

www.shop.com/controller/

Thanks and your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to /application/config/routes.php

Add the default_controller rule like so

`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

So now in /application/controllers/home.php method index() will run on the index page.

Comment: True, but you only need to include the `default` method if you do not have an `index` method. If you want a default controller this it in the `$route` and also define an `index` method in your default controller to have your default page loaded elegantly.

Comment: Note: default threw an error so named it index and it worked well

Comment: Yeah I updated my answer to reflect a more proper and easier answer. As you get further into CI, you'll probably lean away from using the `index` methods and probably start using remap and other things.